# regexmatch doesn't seem to work with minifs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find the min date for sub-tasks that are related to the same Task ID.

Because I want to leave the task min date cell blank if none of the sub-tasks have a date entered, I use the following formula:
=if(SUMPRODUCT(regexmatch($A18:$A,"^Sub-Task "&$B16&".[0-9]*"),$F18:$F=$F16,G18:G<>"")<>0,minifs(G18:G,$A18:$A,regexmatch($A18:$A,"^Sub-Task "&$B16&".[0-9]*"),$F18:$F,$F16,G18:G,"<>"),"")

This breaks downs as follows:

In the SUMPRODUCT function

- I use regexmatch($A18:$A,"^Sub-Task "&$B16&".[0-9]*") to check that I only look at sub-tasks that have the same ID as the specific task "B16"
- I use $F18:$F=$F16 to check that I only look for "Planned" dates, which is in "F16" instead of "Actual" dates
- I use G18:G<>"" to check that I only look for date cells that aren't empty

If the sumproduct results in something, I then use the minifs() function to find the min value of the result.

IF the sumproduct results in nothing, I enter blank "" in the cell

The sumproduct seems to work perfectly well and gives me the results that I expect when I change values around, but the minifs function doesn't seem to work with regexmatch()

Is there a different syntax that has to be used in minifs functions?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result or formula you trying to use

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
REGEXMATCH(A18:A&"", "^Sub-Task "&B16&".*")
```

inserting numeric value in regex will cause VALUE error

Comment: I'm not seeing any change with adding &"" to the range. Don't I need to add a TRUE criteria along with the regexmatch in minifs?

Here is the full minifs expression: minifs(G18:G,$F18:$F,$F16,G18:G,"<>"&"",regexmatch($A18:$A,"^Sub-Task "&B16&"\.*"),TRUE)

Comment: @SessionMwamufiya can you share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, minifs can take regex directly, but only simple ones; it doesn't like characters like "^", and I was able to work around it for my needs.